# How to create a custom directive like v-on in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, directive

I am trying to create a directive with the same behaviour as the v-on (for the sake of learning).
I already can use it passing a function as value, but **I would like to know how to pass code as value**.

Example of usage:

```
<button v-onward:click="print">Test 1</button>
<button v-onward:click="testNumber = testNumber + 1">Test 2</button>
```

Where "print" is a function and "testNumber" is a number in the component data.

What I was trying to do, but with no success:

```
directives:{
        'onward': {
            bind(el, binding, vnode){
                if(typeof binding.value === 'function')
                    el.addEventListener(binding.arg, binding.value);
                else
                    el.addEventListener(binding.arg, function(){
                        binding.value
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```